# How to create a python script to parse a xlsx spreadsheet file and generate sql statements?

Tags: python, xlsx

I have a xlsx file with two columns (id, meal) and 100 rows of data, and I want to parse the data to generate a notepad file that has sql update statements.

| Id | Meal |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Child |
| 23456 | Adult |
| 34567 | Senior |
| 34599 | Senior |

I'm unsure on how to implement if/else/else if statements and add data from the xlsx file to generate sql statements to add into a notepad file.

If the meal is 'Child', an example of the sql script generated would be
`update system.user set meal_name = 'Child', meal_price = 'Child' where customer_id = '12345';`

If the meal is 'Adult', an example of the sql script generated would be
`update system.user set meal_name = 'Adult', meal_price = 'Adult' where customer_id = '23456';`

If the meal is 'Senior', an example of the sql script generated would be
`update system.user set meal_name = 'Senior', where customer_id = '34567';`

Anything to help would be very much appreciated, it's my first experience with Python so I'm unsure on how to get started.

This is the current code I have which doesn't have much, I'm just not sure how to get started

```
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path

xlsx_file = Path('CustomerData', 'customer_data.xlsx')
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_file)
sheet = wb_obj.active

col_names = []
for column in sheet.iter_cols(1, sheet.max_column):
    col_names.append(column[0].value)
   
    
print(col_names)
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing your loop to `for column in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=2, sheet.max_column):` so that it gets both column one and two.

Comment: There is a library called 'pandas' (`pip install pandas`) that is the standard for dealing with dataframes (essentially the same as tables) and can read excel files with `pandas.read_excel(filename,...)`. If you start with that that you can immediately read in your excel table. https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pandas library, I think we can achieve what you want like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(path) # read our dataframe from excel

all_statements = [] # initialize an empty list to append to
for row in df.itertuples(index=False): # loop over each row
    statement = f"update system.user set meal_name = '{row.Meal}', meal_price = '{row.Child}' where customer_id = '{row.Id}'" # create a statement for that row using f-strings
    all_statements.append(statement) # append the statement for this row to our list of all_statements
    
with open(my_text_file, 'a') as file: # open in append mode, which will add new lines to the end of an existing file
    file.writelines(all_statements)
```

This code will read in your excel table and then loop over the rows to create a statement for each row. I don't think we need to do any `if-else` for creating those statements, since every statement appears to be the same format - it has the same pieces but we replace a few words with the values from the table.

Then we write these lines to your text file. In the last piece here, the file is opened in `'a'` which is for append, and so will append the lines to an existing file (or create a new file if it doesn't already exist). If you want to overwrite what is already in the file, you will just change the `'a'` to `'w'` (for write mode).